# To use Top Command In Batch Mode

Tags: command

How do we use Top command in batch mode to sort based on Swap memory and Virtual memory ?
Like we have "top -m" option to sort per Memory usage.

Comment: Use `ps` and see http://alvinalexander.com/linux/unix-linux-process-memory-sort-ps-command-cpu

Answer (score 0):

Please use `-o` with field name.

```
top -b -o %MEM
```